# Vector Compare to Scalar

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

Is it possible to compare a vector of values to a single scalar value in `Excel`?

Example:

`=IF(A1:Z1 > 0, 1, 0)`

Typically, I've seen the following:

`=IF( AND( A1>0, B1>0, C1>0,` . . . `Y1>0, Z1>0 ), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,">0")=COUNT(A1:Z1),1,0)
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,">0")=COUNTA(A1:Z1),1,0)
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,">0")=COLUMNS(A1:Z1),1,0)
```

depending on which works best in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

Although this doesn't address the generalized question, for your particular example wouldn't this do the trick?

```
=IF( Min(A1:Z1) > 0, 1, 0)
```

If the smallest one is greater than 0, then they all are.  Otherwise there is at least one that is not greater than 0.

Comment: It's amazing what people come up with when they think about things.  :-)

Comment: This is *definitely* simpler than mine for OP's use case. +1